# Can we see comments when editing?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, editor

There are many people who make posts with little information. Often, the details find their way into the comments.

I would love to load the comments when I'm editing a post. I can't always remember everything I wanted to edit in.

So I really want to be able to see what comments are attached to a post when editing it, even if they are hidden at first under `2 more comments`.

---

Edit: I asked this back as a puny <2k user. Now that I have the cool editor, I am able to participate in some of the review queues. While my own edits are done inline, this does not happen in the review queues.

Because I now have more responsibility with my edits, it becomes even more important to do things well.

I feel that being able to view the comments while editing will help me in the review queues, and I think the feature request still has merit because of this.

Comment: Open the edit page in a different tab, or get 2k rep and use the inline editor.  You can middle click the back button to open the question you navigated from in a tab, if you forgot to open a tab for editing.

Comment: Then what's the problem?  You already have a way to see *more* than just the comments on a post.  Also, most input drivers have a way to initiate a middle click event without a scroll wheel, or otherwise open a tab on click.